# PHP Symlink Permission Denied

Tags: php, symlink, permission-denied

I know this question is asked a lot, but I can't seem to find the error why my symlinks sometimes aren't working.

I have two folders:

```
/home/user/domains/example.com/folder1
/home/user/domains/example.com/folder2
```

These are their permissions:

```
drwx--x--x  9 root   root   4096 May 12 11:15 home
drwx--x--x  7 user   access 4096 Feb  9 10:23 user
drwx--x--x  3 user   user   4096 May  5  2014 domains
drwx--x--x 12 user   user   4096 Jul  7 09:52 example.com
drwxr-xr-x  2 apache apache 4096 Jan 21 09:22 folder1
drwxrwxrwx  4 user   user   4096 Jul  9 10:38 folder2
```

in PHP I create two symlinks:

```
symlink("/home/user/domains/example.com/folder1","whatever/folder");
symlink("/home/user/domains/example.com/folder2","whatever/folder");
```

Why is my symlink to folder1 working and my symlink to folder 2 not? I have been looking at it for hours now..

Edit:
Well, as my provider isn't of any help, I'd like to try a different solution: create a symlink and immediately change its owner. This, however, gives me an 'Operation not permitted' error. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Not working in what way? Are you trying to access the folder as a user (`user`) through a terminal, or access it over the web via Apache? If via Apache, what settings?

Comment: It is meant to give access to a folder outside of the webroot (if a user is allowed to) by generating a symlink inside the webroot. It is a construction I have used before and which works, but in that case I only linked to PHP-generated folders. Now I want to link to folders which I have uploaded by FTP (and many folders to upload in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the symbolic links were created successfully, `folder2` most likely yields a permission error when Apache is configured to only follow symbolic links if the owner matches; you're looking for this specific configuration option:

```
SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

You could make Apache less rigid by using the following option instead:

```
FollowSymLinks
```

Alternatively, fix the ownership of the symbolic link target to make it work.

Comment: This might be the case (the symlinks are indeed created succesfully). How can I change these Apache settings? I have a hosting package that includes DirectAdmin and have ssh-access to the server, but I've never messed with Apache options before

Comment: `chown apache.apache folder2` should do it.

Comment: This has been suggested before, but it is not a solution I can work with (I'd have to do this for all future folders uploaded by ftp). I meant how to configure the 'FollowSymLinks'-option: which file should I look at?

Comment: @sprunk It should be configured in the settings for your domain ... your provider needs to do this for you and reload the web server before it takes effect.

Comment: I've contacted my provider and they've changed every setting they could think of, but still no luck.. Thanks anyway

Comment: What were the settings they could think of?

Comment: They've added this in /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf
        
    < Directory /home >
    AllowOverride All
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +IncludesNoExec +Includes
    < Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND >
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    < /Limit >
    < LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND >
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    < /LimitExcept >
    < /Directory >

Comment: And this in custom httpd configurations (DirectAdmin):
|?ALLOW_OVERRIDE=AllowOverride All|

Comment: Now they recommend to install mod_ruid2, but I don't know what consequences this will have for other applications that are already on this server.

Comment: Then, my next suggestion would be to check the permissions of each intermediate path of `/home/user/domains/example.com/folder2` and see if any of those prohibits access (x).

Comment: I've posted the permissions in the opening post -> every folder has execute rights for 'world'

Comment: Setting every path to 717 doesn't change a thing

Comment: @sprunk It need (r) as well, so chmod 755 for all should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't.. We have tested in on some other servers (including one of the same provider) and the configuration works just fine, so we have given our hosting provider a last chance to solve the problem.
I've marked your answer as correct, since it should be the correct answer, but for some reason our server has some hidden blocking features. We'll wait and see!

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete both symlinks then 1) try PHP again and see if it persists and 2) logging in via SSH and create the same links using ln instead, for example

```
ln -s whatever/folder /home/user/domains/example.com/folder1
```

If that works, then it is probably a permission issue with the folder you are linking from or into, that the apache server / PHP cannot address

Comment: The symlink is created (as it is in my first configuration), but when I try to open it, I get a 403 Permission Denied

Answer (score 0):

Does `whatever/folder` have enough permissions?

Remove folder1 and folder2 then Try

```
symlink("/home/user/domains/example.com/folder1.txt","whatever/folder");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the user group of folder2 from user:user to apache:apache

```
chown -R apache:apache folder2
```

The reason is because Apache needs the group permissions rather than a normal user.

Comment: If you look at folder1 (which is working), you can see the user group is apache:apache, so this is why I think that's the issue. :)

Comment: Well yes, this works, but it is a solution in the wrong direction.
I'll give more details:
I'm building a portal to my applications which are in a folder outside of the webroot. The portal is, of course, inside the webroot. It should be an application that checks whether a user has the right to see an application and, if so, generate a symlink to that application.